# EXCEL VBA - count using dictionary and array

Tags: vba, excel

the following code is trying to combine the values in column G and S and then count how many times each value appears.

However when I run this code, the number returns is always the last row number, which I believe it feels all the values are the same. How can I fix this?

This is just the core part of the whole code, so some variables might be defined in the earlier lines.

```
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("BL2:BL" & lastrow).Formula = "=G2&""_""&S2"
Const CB_COL As Long = 64

Dim d2 As Dictionary

Set d2 = New Dictionary

    For i = 2 To lr
        If Not d2.Exists(arr(i, CB_COL)) Then
        d2.Add arr(i, CB_COL), 1
        Else
        d2(arr(i, CB_COL)) = d2(arr(i, CB_COL)) + 1
        End If
    Next

    For i = 2 To lr
        arr(i, CB_COL + 1) = d2(arr(i, CB_COL))
    Next


    With Worksheets("Raw Data")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, CB_COL + 1)) = arr
    End With
```

Comment: this is a little confusing for me. `arr(i, CB_COL)` should contain a column of values with duplicates. However, subsequently, you are looping through `arr` again and assigning in `CB_COL` + 1 the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found where the problem was myself...
I should have combined that two columns earlier, before the array was defined... otherwise this column in the array is actually totally blank.